# 84 "Unspecified" javascript error in IE 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

In my application, I will show a popup screen using thickbox. On click of a button in the popup a ajax request will be sent and the pop up will be closed.

The functionality works fine most of the time. However, I am getting a javascript error stating "unspecified". I am getting this error **rarely**(atleast twice a day). I couldnt find any specific scenario.

I am getting the error only in IE 6 . Not in Ie 7 or 8, Firefox.

I tried attaching the debugger(Microsoft Script debugger) and reproduce the issue. However when the debugger is attched I am getting the below error,

"A debugger break at "Jscript anonymous function" couldnt be handled because the source document could not be found."

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, it looks like you're using an 11 year old browser that is no longer supported by Microsoft anymore. :) In all seriousness, *why* are you supporting IE 6?

Comment: Since our end clients are using Ie6, we need to support :(

Comment: Well, then i think the next logical step would for you to actually show some code. :)